# JSF 2.2 exception in Liferay

Tags: jsf, liferay, jsf-2.2, java-ee-7, glassfish-4

I try to deploy my jsf-portlet on Glassfish 4 with JSF 2.2. Last liferay-faces-bridge-impl (3.1.2) supported only JSF 2.1, so i have to use 4.1.0-ga1-SNAPSHOT (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/ repository), but getting exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.liferay.faces.bridge.context.map.RequestAttributeMap
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As of today (18 June, 2013) the 4.1.x branch of Liferay Faces branch for JSF 2.2 has not reached stability. Please click on the "watch" link in JIRA for FACES-1459 [1](http://issues.liferay.com/browse/FACES-1459) and [FACES-1531](http://issues.liferay.com/browse/FACES-1531) for updates on progress. If I may ask, what is the timeline for your project to start development, and then to go production?

Comment: We working with current project over 5 months, but i wanted to do branch for testing on Glassfish 4.